# How to clean prerender cache and how to set prerender cache period?

Tags: caching, prerender

I have a local install of prerender with headless chrome. How do we remove cached pages and how do we set cache period?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There are two plugins for caching on a self-hosted Prerender instance:

- https://github.com/prerender/prerender-memory-cache
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/prerender-level-cache

Based on what you use, the resetting the cache and setting the cache's TTL is described there.

Answer (score 0):

The open source version of the Prerender server does not include the caching/recaching functionality that our hosted service has at https://prerender.io/. You'd have to build that out yourself.